# Rails Active Record has nil id after commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I registered an after_commit trigger for one of my Active Record entities, like so:

```
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_commit :on_work_commit

    ...

    def on_work_commit
        puts self.id # prints nil sometimes
    end
end
```

The problem is that in my production environment, self.id is sometimes nil 
inside the on_work_commit method. It doesn't happen all the time, in fact, it happens intermittently. By analysing the stack trace of these errors, I can see that they happen intermittently during the work creation operation, but never when updating a work. I am unable to reproduce this problem locally though, as it only happens in production when a lot of works are being created and updated at the same time.

This kind of problem screams race condition to me, but I have no idea what could be wrong. Is there any scenario where an after_commit trigger could be called for an object before the object could get an id?

I'm using rails version 3.2.22 and ruby version 1.9.3-p484.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Not yet! We are ignoring it for now and will come back to it later. I'll update this as soon as we find out what was the cause.

Comment: Are your tests wrapped in a transaction, e.g.`use_transactional_fixtures` or database cleaner transaction strategy. Changing to truncation might help. But then if your after_commit is being fired you can't be wrapping your tests in a transaction...

Answer (score 6):

`after_commit` method also executes for `destroy` action, that's why its returning `nil` when you are trying to delete an item, do this instead

```
after_commit :on_work_commit, on: [:create, :update]
```

I would suggest you to use `after_save` for this purpose

```
after_save :on_work_commit
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sadly, these errors are not related to the destroy action. The Work entity has mechanisms that ensure it is never destroyed, and is soft deleted instead. Furthermore, the code inside the on_work_commit method throws an error when the id of the work is nil, which generates a stack trace that tells me the error is happening when the work is created.